# Как скрыть обьекты в Viewport-е если они не относятся к UI unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Добавляю обьекты в content ScrollView. Добавляю к viewport  mask и обьекты не скрываются в отличии от ui,
можно ли подобное провернуть с обычными обьектами?

Comment: Сделать их. UI, RawImage.

Comment: а кроме этого других вариантов нет?

Comment: Я делаю через RawImage и норм)
Также и выношу всякие 3д модельки если очень надо